# "System.InvalidOperationException: Permission denied to access property" when using Selenium with Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a set of test cases in Selenium using C# that run perfectly on Chrome and on Edge, but when I execute them in Firefox they perform all the steps until the assertion and at that point the execution fails showing me the following error message:

> Result Message:   System.InvalidOperationException : Error: Permission
>   denied to access property "invoke"

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT =

Well... the code for the creation of the IWebDriver is this:

```
        IWebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return Driver;
```

And all the interactions with the browser work alright until I do this:

```
            Assert.AreEqual(this.Map.ErrorMessage.Displayed, displayed);
```

ErrorMessage is an IWebElement object.

I think that this must be a configuration issue with the Firefox browser because the same code works perfectly with Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Can you add some code...?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/616 Are you using zonejs?